# Security of simple Skein PBKDF mentioned in the paper

Tags: pbkdf-2, scrypt, skein, pbkdf, memory-hard

From the [Skein 1.3 paper section 4.8, Skein as a Password-Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF)](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/skein1.3.pdf), it mentions the following as a simple PBKDF (*S* = seed and *P* = password):

> An even simpler PBKDF is to simply create a very long repetition of *S* and *P*; e.g., *S*||*P*||*S*||*P*||*S*..., and hash that using Skein. (Any other optional data can also be included in the repetition.) This approach is not ideal with a normal hash function, as the computation could fall into a loop. But in Skein, every block has a different tweak and is thus processed differently.

The advantages I can see is that it is very simple to implement and hard to break the implementation accidentally.

Is this a more effective PBKDF than PBKDF2?

What about being more effective than Scrypt?

Is this a memory hard approach as well as CPU intensive? I imagine for a large length string e.g. 256 bit length seed + 256 bit length password (32 ASCII chars), repeated 100,000 times, this would force an attacker to use 6MB~ of memory to test one password. I imagine this could be easily customized to use the amount of memory required to be significantly slow for calculation and also require x MBs of memory per calculation.

What is a strong security level using this method? E.g. how many repetitions of the Seed and Password would be required? 100,000? 1000,000?

Comment: Why would it be memory-hard? The hashing code only processes one block at a time, you don't need the entire input in memory all at once (otherwise hashing 20Tb files would be quite challenging).

Comment: It's not memory hard and is comparable to PBKDF2. Scrypt and bcrypt are still better.

Comment: @Thomas, it would require a closer look at the Skein internals, but perhaps it requires the output from previously processed blocks to still be in memory to compute the final digest?

Comment: @Thomas, don't you at first need to construct the x MB long string and pass it to the Skein function, thus the program is using at least x MB to do that? Or are you saying there could be a way for an attacker to tweak the Skein function implementation so it pulls in a smaller x bits of the seed and password at a time in order to hash them separately in order to reduce memory usage?

Comment: @504811E There's no need to tweak it, that's how it already works by default: the "normal" implementation is one "initialization" function, an "update" function that you can call as many times as you want with successive input strings (that get processed sequentially) and a "finalization" function that returns the final hash for all the input data passed to the update function calls. The function that takes in a single buffer is a convenience function for when all the data is known in advance or is small enough and just happens to only call the update function once.

Comment: @504811E In other words, memory usage is already independent of the length of the input.